# Continuing a project using PyCharm instead of Visual Studio

Tags: django, pycharm

I am currently in the middle of a Django project and am considering switching from Visual Studio Code to PyCharm, but after activating the virtual environment, it is not showing any Project Interpreter.

Also when I type `python manage.py runserver` in the terminal, it is saying:

> bash: python: command not found

Is there a way to continue the project using PyCharm or do I have to install everything from the start?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can proceed using any other IDE, in your case PyCharm.

Make sure that you define the Python variable in your PyCharm Settings so everything can be interpreted accordingly and to ensure that all required packages are accessible.

Go to File/Settings/project:Foo in your PyCharm IDE and then check for the Interpreter to be set up.

[image]

Additionally you might consider to scan/run your `requirements.txt` once again. Just to be sure.

Comment: when i try to run the ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` I get  ```bash: pip: command not found``` Also I can't find any packages in the Project Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

if your using linux then install django to your project,  pip install django